# Prevent HTML-div (box) from growing

Tags: html, overflow

I'd like to keep a div (a CSS3 box) to a certain width. But somehow, overflow:hidden and max-width seem to be ignored.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="display:-moz-box;">
  <!-- Keep the red div 100 px wide, regardless of its content. But how? -->
  <div style="background-color:red; padding:2px; width:100px; max-width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="width:500px; border: 1px solid yellow;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently testing in Firefox 6.

Comment: add !important to your overflow, probably overwritten by inheritance. "overflow:hidden !important;"

Comment: @Senad - hmm, worth trying, but unlikely to have overridden an inline style.

Comment: The problem is being caused by the `display:-moz-box` as it works ok in Chrome. Will `display:inline-block` acheive the effect you're after?

Comment: There is no inheritance. The example above is a self-contained minimal example. `inline-block` shows the same behavior. Would you consider this behavior a bug?

Comment: @mh123 On my Firefox (6.0.2) `inline-block` doesn't exhibit the same behaviour at all. The `div` ends up at 104 pixels (100 + 2x2 padding) and the following `div` is below it.

Comment: @Gareth Oh, you mean `inline-block` for the outer div? Okay, that changes the bahavior completely. Youself state that the two inner divs are not side by side any more. Furthermore, I need some of the (-moz-)box functionaliy, so having a CSS3 box is an intrinsic part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of research uncovered [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625700) bug report. You may need to find another way of doing what you want for the moment.